# Who are the football players that have scored in every minute of a football match?

Tags: football, trivia, records

Who are the footballers that have scored at least one goal in each minute from the first to 90th?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. [Cristiano Ronaldo](http://messivsronaldo.net/records/)
2. [Zlatan Ibrahimović](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-2746046/Zlatan-Ibrahimovic-scored-EVERY-MINUTE-football-match.html)
3. [Luis Suarez](https://www.thesun.co.uk/sport/16232148/luis-suarez-goalscoring-feat-every-minute-match/)

[Lionel Messi](https://messi.starplayerstats.com/en/bingo) is the other footballer who has a chance to achieve this, if he scores in the 1st minute.